# Custom Authentication with Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: .net, authentication, azure, azure-web-app-service, custom-authentication

I'm using the new Azure Mobile Apps (not the old Mobile Services) as backend for my Xamarin-App. Mobile Apps comes with a bunch of Social Authentication Options (e.g. Twitter, Facebook...), but I want my own authentication with my own account table.

For the old mobile services custom auth is described here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/
This approach uses a `LoginProvider`, which isn't available anymore in Mobile Apps. The documentation for migrating from Mobile Services to Mobile Apps just says:

> One of the biggest differences between Mobile Apps and Mobile Services is that login is handled by the App Service Gateway in the case of Mobile Apps, not the code site.
>   http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-migrating-from-mobile-services-preview/

What does that mean? How can I implement custom auth?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom authentication is currently not available in Mobile Apps, see [comment from azure app service documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-users-preview/#comment-1955547752)

It should become available when Mobile Apps is Generally Available (GA). I have the same login requirements and had to use Mobile Services for now.

Comment: thanks, i found some more comments saying the same. hope the migration won't be too difficult when mobile apps becomes GA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a update from azure team
There is, currently as a preview for ASP.NET - you can use the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login NuGet package to do this for now. More about that here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-mobile-apps-november-2015-update/